# Append column table into different row dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I Have Table like this snippet below

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" >Tgl. Group Temuan</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Ket</td>
      <td colspan="3">Temuan Pemeriksaan (TP)</td>
      <td colspan="3">TP yang ditindak lanjuti (TP)</td>
      <td rowspan="2">TPB s/d Bulan Ini</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>TP s/d Bulan Lalu</td>
      <td>TP Bulan ini</td>
      <td>TP s/d Bulan ini</td>
      <td>TP s/d Bulan Lalu</td>
      <td>TP Bulan ini</td>
      <td>SUB TOTAL</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td rowspan="2"></td>
   <td>Kejadian</td> 
   <td ></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
     <div id="kej"></div>
    
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Rp</td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   //this part that i want to add the td using jquery
   <tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
     <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">TOTAL</td>
      <td>Kejadian</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      //this part too
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rp</td>
         <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <div id="kej"></div>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have other `<td>` that i want to append it into my table. In my table, there is rowspan that makes me confuse how can add the `<td>` dynamically using jquery while the it has a different `<tr>` ?

What i want to add is this data div with id `kej` ( you can see in my snippet )

I have tried

```
var html = '<td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td>'; 
$('#kej').append(html);
```

It give me result nothing and i dont know how do i append in booth tr.

```
//FOR THE FIRST 'kej' id ROW  
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
//FOR THE SECOND 'kej' id ROW
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
<td>0</td>
```

This is the result that i want

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="form-group">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <td rowspan="2" >Tgl. Group Temuan</td>
      <td rowspan="2">Ket</td>
      <td colspan="3">Temuan Pemeriksaan (TP)</td>
      <td colspan="3">TP yang ditindak lanjuti (TP)</td>
      <td rowspan="2">TPB s/d Bulan Ini</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>TP s/d Bulan Lalu</td>
      <td>TP Bulan ini</td>
      <td>TP s/d Bulan ini</td>
      <td>TP s/d Bulan Lalu</td>
      <td>TP Bulan ini</td>
      <td>SUB TOTAL</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td rowspan="2"></td>
   <td>Kejadian</td> 
   <td ></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
     <div id="kej"></div>
       <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td>Rp</td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
   <td></td>
    <div id="kej">
     <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td></div>
   <tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
     <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">TOTAL</td>
      <td>Kejadian</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
     
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rp</td>
         <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
     
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you explain clearly?

Comment: @ShadowFiend i have edit my question please check it out

Comment: You said that you got the result that you want. So what's this question for?

Comment: i dont know how to add it using jquey ( dynamically ) in the result i want, i add the td manually

Comment: You are not not using 'td' correctly. You can't just place it inside a 'div'. TD is a table component, so it should be the immediate child of a TR

Comment: @Gagantous try my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```js
$(".kej td:last-child").each(function(){
  $(this).after("<td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
          <td rowspan="2" >Tgl. Group Temuan</td>
          <td rowspan="2">Ket</td>
          <td colspan="3">Temuan Pemeriksaan (TP)</td>
          <td colspan="3">TP yang ditindak lanjuti (TP)</td>
          <td rowspan="2">TPB s/d Bulan Ini</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>TP s/d Bulan Lalu</td>
          <td>TP Bulan ini</td>
          <td>TP s/d Bulan ini</td>
          <td>TP s/d Bulan Lalu</td>
          <td>TP Bulan ini</td>
          <td>SUB TOTAL</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
       <tr class="kej">
       <td rowspan="2"></td>
       <td>Kejadian</td> 
       <td ></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="kej">
       <td>Rp</td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
         <tr>
          <td rowspan="2">TOTAL</td>
          <td>Kejadian</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
         
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Rp</td>
             <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
          <td>0</td>
         
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your table structure first then please use [this](https://jsbin.com/sexeqem/edit?html,output) as reference. You can see it dynamically add new row to the table.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>Heading 1</td>
        <td>Heading 2</td>
        <td>Heading 3</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Default td1</td>
        <td>Default td1</td>
        <td>Default td1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
  <button id="addNewRow">Add New Record</button>
  <script>
$(document).ready(function (){

          var newRow = "<tr><td>New Row</td><td>New Row</td><td>New Row</td></tr>"
          $('#addNewRow').click(function(){
            $('#myTable tbody').append(newRow);
          });

});
  </script>
```

Comment: i fixed some of my question with the resukt i wnt please chek it out

Comment: You are not not using 'td' correctly. You can't just place it inside a 'div'. TD is a table component, so it should be the immediate child of a TR

Comment: so i should remove the div ?

Comment: if you remove the 'div', it will completely mess your table structure.

Comment: how do i make the td append into the specific row ?

Comment: i want the td append in column `TP s/d Bulan Lalu `, `TP Bulan ini`, and `SUB TOTAL` only. Just like the result i want.  it will appen both `tr` dynamically

Comment: do you have dynamic rows?

Comment: just the append part that i want to add dynamically